# Python - Efficient extracting data from list of tuples to another list

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tuples

Multiprocessing called function generates raw_data list containing tuples (index_i, index_j, some_result). It is normally quite a large list, but here is some short example:

```
raw_data = [(0, 0, 1.0),
(0, 1, 0.8006688952445984),
(0, 2, 0.7255614995956421),
(0, 3, 0.7885053157806396),
(0, 4, 0.9278563261032104),
(0, 5, 0.8481519222259521),
(0, 6, 0.5808478593826294),
(0, 7, 0.7729462385177612),
(0, 8, 0.4846215844154358),
(0, 9, 0.6634186506271362),
(1, 1, 1.0), 
(1, 2, 0.9437128305435181), 
(1, 3, 0.9655782580375671), 
(1, 4, 0.8094803690910339), 
(1, 5, 0.7461609840393066), 
(1, 6, 0.6327897906303406), 
(1, 7, 0.7813301682472229), 
(1, 8, 0.5511380434036255), 
(1, 9, 0.7230715155601501), 
(2, 2, 1.0), 
(2, 3, 0.9496157765388489), 
(2, 4, 0.6908014416694641), 
(2, 5, 0.6450313925743103), 
(2, 6, 0.510845422744751), 
(2, 7, 0.6914690732955933), 
(2, 8, 0.4440484046936035), 
(2, 9, 0.6007179617881775), 
(3, 3, 1.0), 
(3, 4, 0.7783468961715698), 
(3, 5, 0.7336279153823853), 
(3, 6, 0.6183328032493591), 
(3, 7, 0.7425610423088074), 
(3, 8, 0.4954148828983307), 
(3, 9, 0.6851986646652222), 
(4, 4, 1.0000001192092896), 
(4, 5, 0.916759729385376), 
(4, 6, 0.6729019284248352), 
(4, 7, 0.8551595211029053), 
(4, 8, 0.4803779423236847), 
(4, 9, 0.7606569528579712), 
(5, 5, 0.9999998807907104), 
(5, 6, 0.7227450013160706), 
(5, 7, 0.8301199078559875), 
(5, 8, 0.47183749079704285), 
(5, 9, 0.7638712525367737), 
(6, 6, 1.0), 
(6, 7, 0.8355474472045898), 
(6, 8, 0.5089120864868164), 
(6, 9, 0.8670180439949036), 
(7, 7, 1.0000001192092896), 
(7, 8, 0.4481610059738159), 
(7, 9, 0.9298642873764038), 
(8, 8, 0.9999999403953552), 
(8, 9, 0.43459969758987427), 
(9, 9, 0.9999998807907104)]
```

Now I need to transform raw_data into clean_data (clean_data is already initialized) taking first two values from tuples as an indexes of elements in clean_list and third value as an values of those elements:

```
for item in raw_data:
    clean_data[item[0]][item[1]] = item[2]
```

This is working but it is taking to much time. I am sure it could be done in much more efficient way, maybe with numpy.take or numpy.choose, but I did not manage to figure it how. :-(

Comment: does the data form a variant of a lower or upper triangulation (ie np.triu, np.tril) ? columns a, b, c... c = np.array(raw_data)[:, 2]

Comment: @NaN
Yes, actually those indexes form an upper triangle of whole clean_data. But that is second phase for me: to take those upper triangle values, transposed it and sum it without diagonale into full clean_data list. Do you have an idea to merge those steps into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the end, I decided not to return indexes with results from multiprocessing function. So, having nothing but results, with ideas from @Nan and @AlexK (thanks guys!), I put those results into upper triangle matrix, and using numpy functions create symmetric matrix of results.

```
clean_data[np.triu_indices(dim)] = raw_data # Upper triangle with diagonale
clean_data += clean_data.T - np.diag(clean_data.diagonal()) # Full matrix
```

where dim is dimension of clean_data matrix. Now I get results very, very, very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is faster, but here is a solution using Numpy that produces a two-dimensional Numpy array filled with values.  It initializes a zero-filled array with the shape based on the maximum values of the first and second elements of your tuples, respectively.  And some of the values remain as 0's in this solution, since in your example there is not a value for every possible combination of x and y.  You said your clean_data is already initialized, so you can update this code (or ask for follow-up in comments if necessary).

```
import numpy as np

#initialize zero-filled two-dimensional array
result = np.zeros((int(np.amax(np.array(raw_data)[:,:1]))+1,int(np.amax(np.array(raw_data)[:,1:2]))+1))

#parse raw_data to get just the values and indices
vals = [np.array(raw_data)[:,2]]
pos = np.array(raw_data, dtype=int)[:,:2]
rows, cols = pos[:,0], pos[:,1]

#update result array with values
result[rows,cols] = vals

result

array([[1.        , 0.8006689 , 0.7255615 , 0.78850532, 0.92785633,
        0.84815192, 0.58084786, 0.77294624, 0.48462158, 0.66341865],
       [0.        , 1.        , 0.94371283, 0.96557826, 0.80948037,
        0.74616098, 0.63278979, 0.78133017, 0.55113804, 0.72307152],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.94961578, 0.69080144,
        0.64503139, 0.51084542, 0.69146907, 0.4440484 , 0.60071796],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.7783469 ,
        0.73362792, 0.6183328 , 0.74256104, 0.49541488, 0.68519866],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.00000012,
        0.91675973, 0.67290193, 0.85515952, 0.48037794, 0.76065695],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.99999988, 0.722745  , 0.83011991, 0.47183749, 0.76387125],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.83554745, 0.50891209, 0.86701804],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.00000012, 0.44816101, 0.92986429],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.99999994, 0.4345997 ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.99999988]])

#If needed, you can convert this array to list, e.g., result.tolist().
```

Comment: result[rows,cols] = vals;
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Regardless of this little mistake, the process takes a long time on the overall set of data, so unfortunately, that is not what I need. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It was not a mistake in my code, because "result" is not a list in my code.  My code converts it to list at the end of the process, if needed, as you can see from the last comment in the code.